# How to define a protocol that contains an enum with values it defines itself and one of them is stored as an attribute?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

```
protocol TrackableAction {

    var identifier: String { get }

}

struct ServerAction: TrackableAction {

    let identifier = "Server"

    enum Label: String {

        case NotImplemented = "Feature not implemented"
        case NotPlanned = "Feature is not planned in this version"

    }

   var label: Label

}

struct ClientAction: TrackableAction {

    let identifier = "Client"

    enum Label: String {

        case NoneExisting = "Does not exist"
        case CannotFindRoot = "The root was unknown"

    }

   var label: Label

}
```

usage:

```
ServerAction(label: .NotImplemented)
ClientAction(label: .NoneExisting)
```

Is it possible to extend the TrackableAction to have the duplicated enum and label definition included?

I want this to be able to send objects of that type to a function

```
func log(trackableAction: TrackableAction) {
    // sends strings to a log service
    print(trackableAction.label) // ERROR

}
```

Comment: If you want to declare enum inside of protocol, you can't.

Comment: One solution I see here is to remove enums altogether, declare `label` as `String` and move it to protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protocol TrackableAction {

    var identifier: String { get }
    var label: Label {get set}
    associatedtype Label: RawRepresentable
}

struct ServerAction: TrackableAction {

  let identifier = "Server"

  enum Label: String {

    case NotImplemented = "Feature not implemented"
    case NotPlanned = "Feature is not planned in this version"

  }

  var label: Label = Label.NotImplemented

}

func log<T: TrackableAction>(trackableAction: T) {
  // sends strings to a log service
  print(trackableAction.label) // ERROR
}
```

Comment: Looks really promising, except i cannot send TrackableAction as a parameter to the 'func log(trackableAction: TrackableAction) {' method with this solution

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't see that, yeah I was doing the same haha :)

Answer (score -2):

Example of protocol inherited by enum

```
   protocol validator{

        var id : String{ get }
    }

    enum testEnum: validator{
        case african
        case european
        case unknown

        var id: String{

            return self.getDescription()
        }
        func getDescription() -> String{
            switch self {
            case .african:
                return "African"
            case .european:
                return "European"
            default:
                return "Unknown"

            }
        }
    }

    var c = testEnum.african
    let cDescription = c.id
```